# Validate interface properties

Tags: c#, interface

I have made a interface `IRequest`:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    string EndUserIp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    string TokenId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    string ClientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    int TokenAgencyId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    int TokenMemberId { get; set; }
}
```

and I've implemented this in multiple classes; now I need to validate all the properties:

```
 public static bool ValidateCommon(IRequest request)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ClientId))
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InvalidRequest, "ClientId can not be null or Empty");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.TokenId))
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InValidSession, "TokenID should not be Null or Empty");
        if (!IsValidTokenId(request.TokenId))
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InValidSession, "TokenID is not in correct Format");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.EndUserIp))
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InValidIpAddress, "IP Address should not be Null or Empty");
        if (!IsValidIp(request.EndUserIp))
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InValidIpAddress, "IP Address is not in correct Format");
        if (request.TokenAgencyId < 0)
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InvalidRequest, "TokenAgencyId should be positive Integer");
        if (request.TokenMemberId <= 0)
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InvalidRequest, "TokenMemberId should be positive Integer");
        return true;
    }
```

But I don't want to write this method again and again. So what is the right approach to do the same?

Comment: make it public and place it in a shared location?

Comment: Write utility method :)

Comment: take a look at the namespace [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) and the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: Wait, you have `ValidateCommon` method which is `public` and also `static` then why not use it? Why do you need to write this again and again?

Comment: @ Marc: This is a real point of debate. As I created once a object model, based on role playing characters, I had a constellation like cl_character->cl_humanoid->cl_human->cl_female/cl_male.  So now I want to be this woman a magician, I was thinking of interface "IDoMagic", so cl_female would implement "IDoMagic". There I found it useful to have the mana-points be a field in the interface. My question is: Why COULD this be a bad idea ? For me it looks as a good approach. Magic stuff is encapsulated in interface. Voila. Any disadvantages ?

Comment: @icbytes you misunderstand me; my comment (now deleted, as I edited the question) was not a "code style" one - it was a technical one. Fact: C# interfaces **do not have fields**. They often have *properties*. What you are describing are properties.

Comment: I want to make sure that wherever we are using IRequest interface. It must be validated. If not it should generate compile time error.

Comment: Why not use an `abstract class` and have the validation in there?

Comment: @Belogix actually using multiple interface

Comment: I understand, marc. That's why I could not implement my female magician as I intended, and that's why I ask, why this is not possible ( there must be a reason why they did not allow it in c# ), and I would like to know, which reason this is.

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface called `IRequestValidator` with a function called `Validate` taking a `IRequest`. Implement the interface and instantiate / inject the component when you need to validate your `IRequest`.

This way you get the validation system in one place AND a way to swap it easily at a later time (if you inject your component; if not please use a factory pattern to avoid hardcoding the `new` call to your component in your code).

```
public interface IRequestValidator {
    bool Validate(IRequest req);
}

// at first you have one way of validating elements

public class AllWelcomeValidator: IRequestValidator {
    public bool Validate(IRequest req) {return true; // no validation atm }
}

// later...

public class NowWeGotRulesValidator: IRequestValidator {
    public bool Validate(IRequest req) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ClientId))
            throw new BusinessServiceException(ErrorType.InvalidRequest, "ClientId can not be null or Empty");
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: but in that case i need to implement IRequestValidator in all classes that will not resolve my purpose.

Comment: Unless different IRequest implementations have different validation rules, you would only need one `IRequestValidator` implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to define some pre-conditions, post-conditions and invariants for your interface. I am not an expert but should be able to do something like this:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IRequestContract))]
public interface IRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    string EndUserIp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    string TokenId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    string ClientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    int TokenAgencyId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    int TokenMemberId { get; set; }
}


[ContractClassFor(typeof(IRequest))]
internal abstract class IRequestContract : IRequest
{
    string EndUserIp
    { 
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value), "IP Address should not be Null or Empty");
            Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(!IsValidIp(request.EndUserIp, "IP Address is not in correct Format");
        }
    }

    string TokenId 
    { 
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value), "TokenID should not be Null or Empty");
            Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(!IsValidTokenId(request.TokenId), "TokenID is not in correct Format");
        }
    }

    string ClientId 
    { 
        get
        {
            return null;
        }

        set
        {
            Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value), "ClientId can not be null or Empty");
        }
    }

    int TokenAgencyId 
    { 
        get
        {
            return default(int);
        }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(value < 0, "TokenAgencyId should be positive Integer");
        }
    }

    int TokenMemberId 
    { 
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
             Contract.Requires<BusinessServiceException>(value < 0, "TokenMemberId should be positive Integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Will just need to find a way to pass the error code to the `BusinessServiceEXception` somehow.